# Android C2DM notification top corner?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I know C2DM seems to be messaged about to death, but I can not find my issue with the others listed here at stackOverflow.

So everything works, I register, I get my AuthCode, I send the Push, I receive the push. The only thing i noticed though is that I never see the push in the top corner screen of the of the phone where like the SMS messages do. Is that something I have to code specifically? if so, where can I find resources to do that ?

I have only done a Week's worth of android development, so I am a little green with the basics if this was covered somewhere in 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want a notification to appear, you will need to code that. Take a look at the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) api.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something!